# Predict chances of winning or losing in a Chess Game

Tags: algorithm, prediction, chess

I play chess most days at chess.com and was wondering how an algorithm might predict the result of my next game based on all my chess history at this site: my ratings when playing the previous games, the opponent rating, and whether I won or lost.

Thanks,
Roberto Falk

Comment: We can't answer “[how do I get started](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226103/)” questions because we don't know what you have now, and they require a level of interactivity web sites simply cannot support. Research the issue on Google. Take a course or follow a tutorial. Write some code. Your code doesn't do what you want? Post it here, explain what you want it to do, what it's doing, and why you think the two are different.

Comment: This is a pretty classical machine learning problem. Use "machine learning" as a search term, read up, design a program, and come back here for suggestions on how to improve it.

Comment: Kaggle had a competition on this a few years ago: http://www.kaggle.com/c/chess

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching for a way to **estimate your skill and the skill of your opponent**, look for the [Elo-Rating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system). It was actually developed for that purpose (chess). The Elo-rating changes based on which games you won and lost (and against which opponent, based on their Elo-Rating).

That means, if you win against a strong opponent (compared to your strength), your Elo-Rating will improve a lot. If you win against a weak opponent, your Elo-Rating will improve almost not at all.

The problem is, how to get the Elo-Rating of your opponents. If the website does not offer it, the only way is to compute it yourself. However, you would need ALL games of ALL the players on this website to find out how good they really are. Just the number of won/lost games is worthless if you don't factor in the skill of the opponent. If someone won 100 games against a beginner, he doesn't have to be very good. If someone won 100 games against a very good player, he is much better.

If you are searching for a way to **estimate the current state of a game while playing** (i.e. who is more likely to win after some moves were executed), there are several popular heuristics for chess available. The most simple ones define a value for each piece (strong pieces have a higher value). To see which player has the stronger board, just sum up the values of their pieces.

For some more heuristics (and probably other programming ideas), see here: https://www.chessprogramming.org
There are several very good approaches to estimate the value of a board, much more than I could reasonably write up in an answer.

Comment: I just want to predict, statistically, if I'll win or lose, that's all.

Comment: that link no longer exists, can you update it please